# Regex for selective stripping of HTML

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to parse some HTML with PHP as an exercise, outputting it as just text, and I've hit a snag. I'd like to remove any tags that are hidden with `style="display: none;"` - bearing in mind that the tag may contain other attributes and style properties.

The code I have so far is this:

```
$page = preg_replace("#<([a-z]+).*?style=\".*?display:\s*none[^>]*>.*?</\1>#s","",$page);`
```

The code it returning `NULL` with a `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR`.
I tried this instead:

```
$page = preg_replace("#<([a-z]+)[^>]*?style=\"[^\"]*?display:\s*none[^>]*>.*?</\1>#s","",$page);
```

But now it's just not replacing any tags.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just. Don't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), you can try something like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile("foo.html");
$nodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');
foreach($nodeList as $node) {
    if(strpos(strtolower($node->getAttribute('style')), 'display: none') !== false) {
        $doc->removeChild($node);
    }
}
$doc->saveHTMLFile("foo.html");
```

Comment: Thank you - for actually giving an answer :p

Comment: @Kolink - I just edited, made it a bit more robust by incorporating `strpos` to make it work when there are additional style elements present, yet there are still plenty of potential improvements. For example, trimming the attribute using `trim` and also testing for 'display:none' (no space).

Comment: I gave you an answer. But just not the whole solution.

Comment: @karim: I used preg_match instead, to handle `display: none` with a variable amount of spaces. I also needed to use `$node->parentNode->removeChild($node)` - it works now. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kolink - Can you edit your fixes into my answer? I did not get a chance to test.

Answer (score 2):

You should never parse HTML with Regex. That makes your eyes bleed. HTML is not *regular* in any form. It should be parsed by using a DOM-parser.

[Parse HTML to DOM with PHP](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)